# Recoil asynchronous Issue

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

I am a novice at Recoil.
I have a question about Recoil asynchronous

In case of below code

```
    const usersState = atom({
      key: "userInfo",
      default: { email: "", name: "" }
    });
```

First, if I have to update the name of userInfo first

```
const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useRecoilState(usersState);
const s = { email: "testk@gmail.com" };
setUserInfo({ ...userInfo, ...s });
```

And then update name of userInfo

```
 const s2 = { name: "AJH" };
 setUserInfo({ ...userInfo, ...s2 });
```

How can I achieve that?
I took a look at atom effect, sync effect on recoil homepage,
but I don't understand how to use it

my full code is at
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recoil-vs-redux-forked-de2p9o?file=/src/App.js)

please give me a any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting state is an asynchronous action.
You can however use a callback function to take the *current value* into account:

```
  function handleClick() {
    const s = { email: "testk@gmail.com" };
    setUserInfo((prev) => ({ ...prev, ...s }));

    const s2 = { name: "AJH" };
    setUserInfo((prev) => ({ ...prev, ...s2 }));
  }
```